# TypeError : cannot read properties of (undefined 'method') - ember

Tags: ember.js

I got

```
TypeError: cannot read properties of (undefined ‘method’) at r.init (/a/b/cd/de/assets/vendor-sdfsd234234.js:9594:35
```

When I looked into the 9594 line on character 35 on the vendor file, here is the line that is causing the issue: line 9593: var e=this.request line 9594:

```
this.request,this.method=e.method,this.body=e.body,this.cookies=e.cookies,this.header=e.headers,this.queryParams … this._host=function() {return e.host()}},host:Ember.compoutd(function(){return this._host()}))})
```

How can I troubleshoot to find out what js file is exactly responsible for this issue?

I expected the site to load but unfortunately, it won't pass this error which is displayed on the browser.

Comment: This is saying that `e` is undefined so `this.request` is undefined. Is there a way you can turn off your minification?